# Pronunciation difference between "collar" and "color"

Tags: differences, pronunciation, colors

What is the pronunciation difference between *collar* and *color*? Can a native speaker tell them apart?

Comment: Both vowels have different sounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, native speakers can easily differentiate these words.

If you have trouble with IPA, you can try pronouncing them this way (for American English):

color ≈  *culler* (the vowel is a short "uh" sound)

collar ≈  *caller* (the syllable following *c* is just like the word *all*)

You might try practicing with a sentence like "What color is your collar?" and overemphasize the differences until you get used to the sound.

Comment: This is Californian or Canadian pronunciation; in the East, some of us distinguish between *color* = *culler*, *collar* and *caller*.

Comment: Well, I'm neither from nor have lived in California or Canada; I have lived in New York, DC, and Florida. I think *caller* and *collar* can be distinguishable, but often aren't; I also think the above explanation is an effective way to think about it for someone who can't currently identify any difference between the two words.

Comment: Now that you've brought it up, I agree; this indeed should be an effective way to think about it for somebody who can't currently identify any difference.

Comment: +1 for `What color is your collar?`.

Answer (score 6):

The vowel sound is slightly more open in collar [ɑ] than in color [ʌ].

English pronunciation is not always easy for non native speakers. 
A good thing is to be able to read the [IPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPA). Most bilingual paper dictionaries will give the pronunciation of words in the IPA.
And on monolingual dictionaries on the web you can listen to the word as well:

- [collar](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/pronunciation/american/collar)   /ˈkɑlər/
- [color](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/color)   /ˈkʌlə(r)/

An on the [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/color), the [Freedictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/collar) and lots of others.

On the [University of Iowa website](http://www.uiowa.edu/~acadtech/phonetics/#) there is a very good [flash animation](http://www.uiowa.edu/~acadtech/phonetics/english/frameset.html) that shows all the movements involved when pronouncing each vowel.

Comment: You seem to have listed the British pronunciation of _color_ and American of _collar_, regarding the ending /r/.

Comment: @ Tim: Thanks. I got confused when copy pasting link. I have corrected now. +1

Answer (score 6):

The difference is quite clear in British pronunciation. *Colour* is /ˈkʌlə/, rhyming with *duller*. *Collar* is /ˈkɒlə(r)/, rhyming with *dollar*. (I realize those rhymes may not be much help if *duller* and *dollar* sound the same in American pronunciation.)

Comment: *Color* rhymes with *duller* and *collar* with *dollar* in American pronunciation as well. This may not help if the OP also has trouble telling *duller* and *dollar* apart, though.

Comment: @Peter Shor In which American dialect does "duller" have a /ʌ/ sound? (It's not the same as "dollar", but it's not the same as "color" either. (It's confusing because both the "l-colored" and the standard version of /ʌ/ are written the same way in some schemes, but color definitely has the latter and dull definitely has the former)

Comment: @Random832: I agree with you, they're not quite the same sound. But is it a good idea to confuse someone learning English with l-colored /ʌ/?  I don't think *color* and *duller* are that far apart, but maybe I think that because I distinguish *cot* and *caught*.

Comment: @Peter Shor I suppose our opinions simply differ - most importantly, I think the vowel sounds are further apart than color and _collar_ in the first place. And the issue in pronouncing color correctly is to _not_ make the l-colored sound - so focus on making a "kuh" sound and then add the rest afterward without changing the sound (as in Malvolio's answer) is better than relying on an analogy to "duller" [which the questioner may not know how to pronounce, and which doesn't actually rhyme]

Comment: I don't think cot/caught is really relevant - except in as much as it affects "collar" (and its distinction from "caller", and Malvolio's answer's "aw"), and I distinguish them too in any case.

Comment: @Random832: I brought *cot/caught* up because I think *duller* sounds something like *caller* but not much like *collar*. But if you think *caller* and *collar* sound the same, I don't know how you perceive *duller*.

Comment: I _don't_ think caller and collar sound the same (just that they would logically be the same to someone who doesn't distinguish caught/cot). "duller" has the _l-colored_ version of "ʌ/ə" (i.e. what you get with a stressed syllabic /l/), which I really think sounds more similar (but not identical) to /ʊ/ than to a proper /ʌ/.

Answer (score 1):

What color was the caller's collar? Thinking about the differences makes me question my pronunciation (and kind of makes my brain hurt). The OP had a good question and the answer varies depending on accent. I pronounce color like cahler, but my husband says culler. My pronunciation of collar is similar to that of color, the difference is very subtle and I don't know how to describe it - for color my tongue is more forward giving a slightly more open/hollow vowel. For caller I say cawler - but not with a southern drawl. My husband pronounces collar and caller the same - cahler.

Answer (score -1):

*Color* is pronounced much shorter than *collar*. Pronouncing *collar* you spend a bit more time on the first *coll-* part.

Answer (score -1):

For "collar" you say "caw", opening your mouth to about half-open as you say the vowel.

For "color" you say "cuh", keeping your mouth just barely ajar.

In both cases, the second syllable is just lrrr.

Answer (score -1):

Approximate to Kollar (gentle r) and Culla in British English.